# VisualStudio Designer não gera algumas variáveis

Tags: c#, winforms

No **VisualStudio 2010** estou tendo esse problema, onde alguns componentes não possuem variáveis e os mesmos são inicializados no método `InitializeComponent`.

Porém desta forma os componentes não ficam acessíveis para serem alterados programaticamente, o Designer faz isso em alguns `Forms`, mas não em todos.

- Porque isto ocorre?
- Qual a forma correta  de resolver esta situação?

**Nota**

> Claro que eu posso resolver isso manualmente, porém caso eu precise alterar algo no `Form` o código seria gerado outra vez assim e teria que refazer tudo.

Comment: Aconselho a ler as diretrizes da comunidade de [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Verifiquei e deixei a pergunta mais genérica, de forma a ajudar mais pessoas, acredito que agora ela siga as diretrizes.

Comment: isto mesmo, eu editei a sua questão para alguns melhoramentos, por fim está muito melhor que antes a sua forma de perguntar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem uma propriedade do componente `Generate Member` que controla se o componente vai ter uma variável. Normalmente ele deveria ser `true` mas as vezes ele vem setado como falso por algum motivo.